# Why does importing a file from a folder work, but calling a file from an imported folder doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Im currently working on a project with the main file being in a directory together with a subdirectory with some additional files:

```
project
|- folder
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- file1.py
|  |- file2.py
|  |- file3.py
|- main.py
```

With the init file being empty. 
In my case, I would like to import all files to my current main.py with **as little code as possible**. Heres the catch:

#### Works

```
from folder.file1 import somefunction1
from folder.file2 import somefunction2

somefunction1()
somefunction2()
```

#### Works

```
from folder import file1
from folder import file2

file1.somefunction1()
file2.somefunction2()
```

#### Does not work

```
import folder
folder.file1.somefunction1()
folder.file2.somefunction2()

AttributeError: module 'folder' has no attribute 'file1'
```

I get the meaning of the error messsage, but not really why it comes up. In my first example, i can call folder.file and folder.file2 as attributes, but in my last example I can't?

Unfortunately I've only found similar questions asking how to import files from folders in general, but nothing about this specific issue.

**What exactly is Python doing in the background and is there a way to fix my issue?**

Comment: What is in your `__init__.py`? I think in order for the 3rd one to work, in the `__init__.py` you have to include `import file1` and `import file2`.

Comment: Its currently empty, inserting `import file1` gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'` (And yes, my file is named the exact same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
from . import file1
```

in your _*init*_.py
this brings file1 in folder which you can then access from main.py

Answer (score 1):

in your **init**.py file

```
__all__ = ["file1","file2","file3"]
```

in main.py

```
from folder import *

file1.somefunction1()

file2.somefunction2()
```